# Creation of scatter_matrix

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get a chart similar to the one pubished [here](http://thegrimmscientist.com/2014/10/23/tutorial-decision-trees/). In my dataset I have 3 features and 1 binary target. When target=0, then the dots should be colored e.g. in red. When target=1, then the dots should be colored e.g. in blue.

When I run this code, it looks like all dots have the same color:

```
from pandas.tools.plotting import scatter_matrix
scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2, figsize=(6, 6), diagonal='kde')
```

How to I specify different colors for target values 0 and 1, so that I can observe possible groupings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To plot this data using the `pandas` `plotting` tools, as you are now, pass `color=['blue' if target == 1 else 'red']` as an argument.

However, I recommending using the `seaborn` `pairplot` facility instead. This will result in a plot that is much closer to the one in the tutorial, and to colorize based on a data point you need only specify `hue='my_data_column'` as a parameter. [Cf. here](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html#seaborn.pairplot).

Comment: Thanks for the idea of using `seaborn`. Could you give an example how to do it using this package? I have never used it.

Comment: In this case you want `import seaborn as sns; sns.pairplot(df, figsize=(6, 6), diag_kind='kde', hue='target')`

Comment: Ok, the problem is that when I do `g = sns.pairplot(df[selected_features], hue="target")  g`, then the plot does not appear (I am working in Jupyter). It looks like it's generated, but does not appear. If I do `g.show`, then it gives an error.

Comment: Ah, I solved this small issue putting the command `%matplotlib inline`